# Java Regex help extracting with negative lookahead

Tags: java, regex

I have the reg ex `\\(.*?\\)` to match what ever inside the parenthesis from my text
e.g. `((a=2 and  age IN (15,18,56)) and (b=3 and c=4))`
my output should only contain:

`a=2 and  age IN (15,18,56)`

`b=3 and c=4`

I have tried using negative lookahead, not to match `.*(?!IN)\\(.*?\\)` but not returning what I expect. Can any body help with where I am going wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it match the whole expression, since it is surrounded by parenthesis itself, and `15,18,56` too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to parse nested expressions, and regular expressions alone cannot do that for you. A regular expression will only catch the innermost expressions with `\\(([^(]*?)\\)`

You can use the `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes to code a more complex solution.

Or you can use a parser. For Java, there's [ANTL](http://www.antlr.org/).

I just coded something that might help you:

```
public class NestedParser {

    private final char opening;
    private final char closing;
    private String str;
    private List<String> matches;

    private int matchFrom(int beginIndex, boolean matchClosing) {
        int i = beginIndex;
        while (i < str.length()) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == opening) {
                i = matchFrom(i + 1, true);
                if (i < 0) {
                    return i;
                }
            } else if (matchClosing && str.charAt(i) == closing) {
                matches.add(str.substring(beginIndex, i));
                return i + 1;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public NestedParser(char opening, char closing) {
        this.opening = opening;
        this.closing = closing;
    }

    public List<String> match(String str) {
        matches = new ArrayList<>();
        if (str != null) {
            this.str = str;
            matchFrom(0, false);
        }
        return matches;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NestedParser parser = new NestedParser('(', ')');
        System.out.println(parser.match(
                "((a=2 and age IN (15,18,56)) and (b=3 and c=4))"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want in terms of nested brackets (eg. `((a = 2 and b = 3))`: is this valid or not?)

This regex gets you most of the way there:

`(\(.*?\)+)`

On the input you specified, it matches two groups:

- `((a=2 and age IN (15,18,56))`
- `(b=3 and c=4))` (notice the double-bracket at the end).

It will return everything, including nested brackets. Another variation will return only singly-bracketed expressions:

`(\([^(]*?\))`

The easiest way to test this is through [Rubular](http://rubular.com/).